# Truncating a file/folder name if required (PHP)

Tags: php, logic

For a development task, I was asked to truncate either the filename or folder name, or both if combined they exceed a total length of 200 characters. The logic to doing this is confusing me.

**Name Limits**

> File name maximum size: 100 chars.
> Path name maximum size: 100 chars.

If the file name and/or path name exceeds their limit, but the 200 char limit can still be achieved, it should not truncate the filename or path name.

If the 200 limit cannot be achieved. We should truncate the file name, as the folder name shouldn't keep changing (due to files then being placed in multiple places).

Any guidance here would be great. I'm sure the logic is simple enough, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Show examples, please.

Comment: Impossible to answer, since we have no information to the structure.

Comment: Computer file names. Imagine you have C:\user\you\document\images\LOGIC_HERE - We then have to determine what should be displayed here, which is what the question is. Truncating strings logically, rather than a simple substr for example. What specifically do you need to know? I'll be happy to update.

Comment: Update your question with full examples of input and output.

Comment: What are you both (sectus and D.Schalla) talking about??? The question is understandable and no code example required. "We have no information about the structure" - the only structure here is a string holding a filesystem path to the file - everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The logic to doing this is confusing me.

`C:\user\you\document\images\waytolong.xml`

lets say is abouve 200chars

should the result then:

like
`C:\user\you\document\images\waytolo...`
or
`C:\user\you\document\images\...long.xml`
or
`C:\user\.....\waytolong.xml`

When that is clear, logic will be very simple.